# Solve $\int_0^\infty f(x) \cos(kx) \, dx=\frac {sin(ak)} {k}$ with using Fourier transform

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

$$\int_0^\infty f(x) \cos(kx) \, dx=\frac {\sin(ak)} {k}$$

From the table fourier cos transform of Heasivide function is $\frac {\sin(ak)}{k}$

Let $f(x)\begin{cases}1, &  0\leq x \leq1 
\\
0 & x > 1 \end{cases}$

$$\ F_c(f(x))= \int_0^\infty f(x)\cos(kx) \, dx =  \int_0^1 1\ \cos(kx)\ \text{d} x + 0 = \left[\frac{\sin(kx)}k\right]^1_0 = \frac{\sin(ak)}{k}$$

(not sure of this steps).

without using transform table, How can we get $f(x)=H(a-x)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that your last calculation is wrong, since you pop out a factor $a$ which as not present before.

Heaviside Theta in your case is defined as

$$\theta(a - x) = \begin{cases} 1 & 0 \leq x \leq a \\
0 & x > a
\end{cases}$$

Whence

$$\int_0^{+\infty} \theta(a-x)\cos(kx) \text{d}x = \int_0^a \cos(kx)\ \text{d}x = \frac{\sin (a k)}{k}$$